# Passing $this variable as an argument

Tags: php, oop

I need help in understanding the following php code.

```
    $this->_PageHeader = new PAGE_HEADER($this);
```

I want to understand the functionality of $this argument in PAGE_HEADER($this).

I knew that $this is used inside a class to refer property and methods but in this case, what values will be passed through this argument.

Comment: `var_dump($this)` and you will know it

Comment: It is passing the whole object in constructor as dependency injection.

Comment: Check constructor function of PAGE_HEADER to see what is happining with that.

Comment: This is the constructor of PAGE_HEADER: class PAGE_HEADER {

    function __construct($TemplateOBJ) {
        $this->_Template = $TemplateOBJ;
    }

Comment: If $this->_PageHeader = new PAGE_HEADER($this); is initiated inside of another class, then $this will refer to the constructor of Pageheader or the constructor of the class in which it was initiated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this` contains the current instance of the class you are in. So it means that you pass the current object of the class containing the code `$this->_PageHeader = new PAGE_HEADER($this);` to the constructor of the class `PAGE_HEADER`.

For instance:

```
class A 
{
    public $value = 1;

    public function execute()
    {
        $b = new B($this);
    }
}

class B
{
    public $value = 2;

    public function __construct(A $dep)
    {
        echo $dep->value; // 3
        echo $this->value; // 2
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->value = 3;
$a->execute(); // In this execution, $this is the object $a.
```

This code will output 32.